# Get Binary Image Data From a MatPlotLib Canvas?

Tags: python, email, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to get the binary data from a matplotlib canvas so I can attach it to an email, but the only way I've found to do so is by saying:

```
filename = 'image.png'
canvas.print_figure(filename)
with open(filename, 'rb') as image:
    return image.read()
```

I'd really like to avoid the Disk IO since I don't need to hold onto the file afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `StringIO` object as a file object, which can be given to the `print_png` canvas function.

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
sio = StringIO()
canvas.print_png(sio)
return sio.getvalue()
```

(if you're using Python 3, use `io.BytesIO` instead of `cStringIO`)

Comment: Glad to help :) 

May I ask *why* do you need to access the raw png data of the canvas?

Comment: It's being attached to an email, and I couldn't see the need to keep around the files afterwards.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. I would change the original question and add this explanation, so other people can search "email matplotlib plots" and find this question/answer.

Comment: Complete example using io.BytesIO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766060/python-matplotlib-to-smtplib/21862555#21862555