# Insert Python Objects when sending email using Outlook

Tags: python, email, matplotlib, outlook

Simple question as the title：How can I insert or copy a Python object(like a matplotlib figure object just generated, not saved into the hard drive) into an email sending from Outlook?

I'm not using SMTP module but operate Outlook via win32com.client. Some of current codes are as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import win32com.client
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20,30))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(5,2)

ax = plt.subplot(gs[0,0])
ax.plot(range(10))

obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "Daily Report of Volatility"
newMail.HTMLBody = "<h1> \
                        This is a test \
                    </h1> \
                    <p> \
                        I am a email-robot \
                    </p> \
                    "

newMail.To = "Kyle"

newMail.display()
```

Just want to insert the 'fig' object into the mail body.

Will appreciate any illustration! Thanks a lot!

Comment: did tried this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766060/python-matplotlib-to-smtplib

Comment: @Manoj  Thanks, I think you mean the BytesIO buffer one right?

Comment: Yes.  using BytesIO buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate an image and then add a reference to the message body.