# Add a dynamically generated matplotlib picture in Django home

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I would like to add a dynamically generated picture in my home. I do not want to save the figure, but just show it directly in my home page, after some text.
My `views.py` looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    import random
    import datetime
    import django
    import pylab 
    import PIL, PIL.Image
    import io

    from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

    fig=Figure()
    ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
    x=[]
    y=[]
    now=datetime.datetime.now()
    delta=datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    for i in range(10):
        x.append(now)
        now+=delta
        y.append(random.randint(0, 1000))

    ax.plot_date(x, y, '-')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    graphic1  =django.http.HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(graphic1)
    return render(request, 'personal/home.html',{'graphic':graphic1})
```

Function `index` is already included in the `urls.py`. No problem there. My `home.html` looks like

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}
{% block content %}
<p> Welcome to my website!</p>
{% include "personal/includes/htmlpic.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

My `htmlpic.html` is:

```
{% block graphic  %}
<div id="content">
    <img src= "data:image/png;base64,{{graphic|safe}}" >
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The error: the figure does not show up. It is a broken link like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,&lt;HttpResponse status_code=200, " image png">
```

It clearly copies the status instead of the image in binary (and adds an extra quote). Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here? Or suggest a SO similar Q&A?

PS. I'm a newbie in Django, please be generous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, [using data URIs is usually a bad idea](http://frontend.co.il/articles/avoid-data-uris-english).

In this case, there is no real need for them anyway. Just create a separate view that returns the image. I am using `gnuplot` here for simplicity. The command just prints a png image of a sine function to the stdout. ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144877/get-binary-image-data-from-a-matplotlib-canvas) are some instructions on getting the image data from a matplotlib canvas.) In `views.py`:

```
def my_plot(request):
    import subprocess
    plot = subprocess.check_output(['gnuplot', '-e', 'set terminal pngcairo; plot sin(x)'])
    response = HttpResponse(plot, content_type="image/png")
    return response
```

Say you map this view to url `plot`, therefore writing the `urls.py` as in here:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',

    url(r'^$', views.index, name='home'),

    url(r'^plot$', views.my_plot, name='plot')
)
```

Then you can simply use the view that generates the image as the source of your image. In `htmlpic.html`:

```
<img src="plot"></img>
```

To me this is a much clearer separation of concerns. One view renders your template, the other renders the image. If you wish to embed this image somewhere else in your program, this way allows you to do so without repeating yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems promising. I'll try it later and mark it as solved if that works to me.