# Django - matplotlib image doesn't display

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I am new to Django and I am trying to display a matplotlib image and some data in a view. The matplotlib is created in a different python file.

Here is the matplotlib code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect


def plot_playoutcomes(playdata):

    fig = Figure()
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    x = np.arange(-2,1.5,.01)
    y = np.sin(np.exp(2*x))
    ax.plot(x, y)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    return response
```

It produces a simple graph. And here is views.py:

```
def getinput(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = get_data(request.POST)

         if form.is_valid():
             down = form.cleaned_data['get_down']
             ytg = form.cleaned_data['get_ytg']
             yfog = form.cleaned_data['get_yfog']
             map_data = next_play.objects.filter(last_dwn__exact=down, last_yfog__exact=yfog, last_ytg__exact=ytg)
             fig = plot_playoutcomes(map_data)
             context = {'form': form, 'query_data': map_data, 'img': fig}
             return render(request, 'play_outcomes/output.html', context)
     else:
         form = get_data()

     return render(request, 'play_outcomes/getinput.html', {'form': form})


def output(request):

    return render(request, 'play_outcomes/output.html', context)
```

It gets data from a form, uses that to query a dataset. Problem is that when I try to display the template the image `{{img}}` doesn't appear.

On the webpage I get this: `<HttpResponse status_code=200, "image/png">` but not image. Help!

Comment: Did you have a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655635/add-a-dynamically-generated-matplotlib-picture-in-django-home

Comment: So it is suggesting to put in a separate view? How would I display data and the image together? Doesn't one view = one page or can I get multiple views on a page?