# How do get the raw plot image data from matplotlib? Instead of saving to file, or displaying

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to be able to send the raw image data somewhere else without ever saving to a file or displaying the plot.
Thank you for the help!

EDIT

Bytes are what I am interested in. I am trying to send the byte image to a web client site and have it be displayed from js/html

Comment: I'm not sure if they actually answer your question, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393769/getting-an-rgba-array-from-a-matplotlib-image) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144877/get-binary-image-data-from-a-matplotlib-canvas) look relevant.

Comment: How raw are we talking?  Likely you'll want to save to an in memory file (BytesIO).

Comment: Could you add a plain python tag please?

Comment: Yeah bytes are what I am interested in. I am trying to send the byte image to a client web site and have it be displayed from js/html.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using canvas as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(4, 4), dpi=300)
ax.plot([1, 3, 5, 8, 4, 2])

fig.canvas.draw()
temp_canvas = fig.canvas
plt.close()
```

at this point, `temp_canvas` contains the "raw" matplotlib plot. You can treat it as a raw image and use it within other libraries such as PIL, for example you can plot it:

```
import PIL
pil_image = PIL.Image.frombytes('RGB', temp_canvas.get_width_height(),  temp_canvas.tostring_rgb())
plt.imshow(pil_image)
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qreEP.png)

Comment: Can the fig.canvas give me bytes or hex?

Comment: Can't seem to find Figure.canvas in the documentation

Comment: I think `fig.canvas.tostring_rgb()` is what you are looking for. It returns the image as a byte sequence.